# После каждого "он" нужно тире?

Tags: тире

*Он ― вождь, он ― король, он ― величайший из величайших.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Тире обычно не ставится**, если подлежащее выражено личным местоимением, а сказуемое — формой именительного падежа существительного:
*Он порча, он чума, он язва  здешних мест* (Крылов);
*Я честный  человек  и никогда не говорю комплиментов* (Чехов).

Но **при логическом подчеркивании** — выделении местоимения — тире **может** ставиться.

> *Я — страница твоему перу.
>
>   Всё приму. Я белая страница.
>
>   Я — хранитель твоему добру:
>
>   Возращу и возвращу сторицей.*
>
> *Я — деревня, черная земля.
>
>   Ты мне — луч и дождевая влага.
>
>   Ты — Господь и Господин, а я —
>
>   Чернозем — и белая бумага!*
>   М. Цветаева

[Все случаи постановки тире](http://rus.1sep.ru/article.php?ID=200202402)

В толковом словаре Ефремовой:
**великий**
1. **м.** Тот, кто необычайно гениальный.

Величайший — превосходная степень к *великий*.
Думаю, что здесь прилагательное выступает в роли существительного:
величайший из величайших = гений из гениев.

Так что (если очень хочется заострить внимание) можно поставить все три тире.